# Altering textFormat of a cell breaks hyperlinks in Google sheet

Tags: php, google-sheets-api

I'm creating a Google Sheet adding content like: `=HYPERLINK("https://example.com","Example")`

Which works fine until I try to alter the cell -> userEnteredFormat -> textFormat

[Here's an example of broken links](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Bf9chvTVkGeAwEWXk8IyFr5G5bMBnE_QZqExGVEmspM/edit#gid=1588559152)

Cell formatting works (see the second sheet).

If I change my config from

```
                  "cell" => [
                            "userEnteredFormat" => [
                                "backgroundColor" => [
                                    "red" => 1.0,
                                    "green" => 1.0,
                                    "blue" => 1.0
                                ],
                                "horizontalAlignment" => "LEFT",
                                "wrapStrategy" => "WRAP",
                                "textFormat" => [
                                    "foregroundColor" => [
                                        "red" => 0.0,
                                        "green" => 0.0,
                                        "blue" => 0.5
                                    ],
                                    "fontSize" => 10,
                                    "bold" => true
                                ]
                            ]
                        ],
                        "fields" => "userEnteredFormat(backgroundColor,textFormat,horizontalAlignment,wrapStrategy)"
```

To

```
                  "cell" => [
                            "userEnteredFormat" => [
                                "backgroundColor" => [
                                    "red" => 1.0,
                                    "green" => 1.0,
                                    "blue" => 1.0
                                ],
                                "horizontalAlignment" => "LEFT",
                                "wrapStrategy" => "WRAP",
                                "textFormat" => [
                                ]
                            ]
                        ],
                        "fields" => "userEnteredFormat(backgroundColor,textFormat,horizontalAlignment,wrapStrategy)"
```

The issue goes away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought that from your request body, I thought that the reason of your issue might be due to `fields`. So, in your situation, how about modifying the value of `fields` as follows?

#### From:

```
"fields" => "userEnteredFormat(backgroundColor,textFormat,horizontalAlignment,wrapStrategy)"
```

#### To:

```
"fields" => "userEnteredFormat(backgroundColor,textFormat(foregroundColor,fontSize,bold),horizontalAlignment,wrapStrategy)"
```

#### Reference:

- [Method: spreadsheets.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate)